# How to read env in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have `docker-compose.yml` in the root of my project, service `frontend` and its directory in the root. Frontend has its own `.env` file. And i need to read that `.env` inside `Dockerfile` of frontend. What I found so far is passing env vars in `docker-compose.yml` but there variables are not being grabbed from /frontend. I also have tried defining `env_file` in config but does not seem to be working. Is there any workaround or I have to create separate docker-compose for frontend ?

Answer (score 1):

`.env` files are for `docker-compose`. You need to use the `docker-compose` cli instead of just `docker`.

You may see [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option).